# Finding index of highest element from a list of list

Tags: python-3.x, list

This is the list i am dealing with. 
Value:

```
[[0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.94, 0.0, 0.0, 0.63, 0.0],
     [0.51, 0.51],
     [0.54, 0.54, 0.0, 0.0,0.63,  0.0, 0.51, 0.54, 0.51, 1.0, 0.51],
     [0.81,0.05, 0.13, 0.7, 0.02]]
```

I have tried to find the highest value belongs to which list. Here the highest value is 1 and its in third list. ie, index 2. 
How to get this?

```
maxval=[]
maxval1=[]
for i in range(0,len(Value)):
        maxval1.append(max(Value[i]))
maxval.append(max(maxval1))


maxval1
Out[220]: [0.94, 0.51, 1.0, 0.81]

maxval
Out[221]: [1.0]

index=[]
index1=[]
for i in range(0,len(Value)):
        index1.append(Value[i].index(maxval))
```

gives error: `ValueError: [1.0] is not in list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching for max value in each list, but it is present in third list only, this will throw `ValueError` for all other lists unless max value is present in first list itself.

It can be done simply like this

```
max_list = list()
for i, sub_list in enumerate(Value):
    max_list.append((max(sub_list), i))

index_of_max = max(max_list)[1]
```

`index_of_max` provides index of list containing max value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as kindof one-liner as well:

```
data = [[0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.94, 0.0, 0.0, 0.63, 0.0],
        [0.51, 0.51],
        [0.54, 0.54, 0.0, 0.0,0.63,  0.0, 0.51, 0.54, 0.51, 1.0, 0.51],
        [0.81,0.05, 0.13, 0.7, 0.02]]

# iL === innerList, abbreviated for 79 chars line width
max_idx, max_value = max( enumerate(max(iL) for iL in data), key = lambda x:x[1])

print(max_idx)
```

Output:

```
2  # max_value == 1, but not printed
```

The trick is to get the `max(..)` of each inner list, `enumerate()` those and use another `max(iterable, key=...)` that has a `key` that selects the highest value (not position) of the enumerate tuple `(position,value)`.

**Advantage** - its using *generators*:

you do not create any intermediary lists but soley work with generators - for big lists this is far more memory friendly then then creating a list like [infiQuanta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53313660/7505395) does.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using the Python's library `pandas`. Solution becomes really simple:

Create a `dataframe`(df) from your list:

```
In [2040]: df = pd.DataFrame(Value)

In [2041]: df
Out[2041]: 
     0     1     2    3     4    5     6     7     8     9     10
0  0.25  0.00  0.00  0.0  0.00  0.0  0.94  0.00  0.00  0.63  0.00
1  0.51  0.51   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  0.54  0.54  0.00  0.0  0.63  0.0  0.51  0.54  0.51  1.00  0.51
3  0.81  0.05  0.13  0.7  0.02  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Now, just find max among each row:

```
In [2047]: df.max(axis = 1)
Out[2047]: 
0    0.94
1    0.51
2    1.00
3    0.81
```

Above, you can see `max` of all rows.

Now, find the `max` value from the above. That will be the max of the whole Dataframe.

```
In [2048]: df.max(axis = 1).max()
Out[2048]: 1.0
```

To, find the index of this value:

## 1-line solution:

```
In [2082]: pd.DataFrame(Value).max(axis = 1).idxmax()
Out[2082]: 2
```

Let me know if this helps.